# Given a trial balance and a financial statement, is there software that can be trained to come up with the mappings between the two?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, hierarchical-data, hierarchical-clustering

If I input a trial balance like this:

- Account 1000   $100
- Account 1001   $250
- Account 2000   $300
- Account 3000   $50

...and a financial statement like this:

- Asset          $350
- Liability      $300
- Equity         $50

Is there software I can feed trial balances in to, that I can train to provide me the mapping/bins between the trial balance and the financial statements?

So, I would want the output to "predict" the relationships between the trial balance line items and the summed/grouped financial statement items.

- Asset

  - Account 1000
  - Account 1001
- Liability

  - Account 2000
- Equity

  - Account 3000

In the real world, the trial balance could be hundreds or thousands of accounts, and the financial statements can be hundreds of groupings/bins.  A line on the financial statement will not always represent sequential account numbers on a sorted trial balance.

Any suggestions on methods and/or tools are appreciated.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: can you explain the rationale behind classifying `Account 1000 $100` into "Asset", etc.?

Comment: A trial balance is just a listing of accounts with their balances.  Usually, accounts that start with 1 are asset accounts, with the first part of the range reserved for cash/bank accounts (10000-19999), the next range reserved for receivables accounts (11000-11999), etc.  Most of the time, the ranges are in sequence, but they are not always in perfect sequence.